# Android studio java object get property

Tags: java, android

```
Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).;  
//  {id: 1, name: "apple", phone: "911", items: [{name: "item 1", price: 1000, discount: 0}]}
```

I want get 'items' how i can it do? and i need get size of "items"?

Comment: You should include it in the model class you use to back the list adapter. That's the most foolproof way

Comment: The starting point would probably be to better understand what type getItemAtPosition() actually returns. So instead of going Object o ... research what the call actually returns.

Comment: please show, example how it make

Answer (score 0):

1: create class Items

```
public class Items implements Serializable
{
    private String name;
    private String price;
    private String discount;

    // getters and setters
}
```

2: create class BaseClass

```
public class BaseClass implements Serializable
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private List<Items> items;

    // getters and setters
}
```

then you will get the items

```
    BaseClass baseClass = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    List<Items> items = baseClass.getItems(); // list of items

    int size = items.size();
```

Comment: it should look like this

`import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class BaseClass implements Serializable
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private List<Items> items;


    public List<Items> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
`

Comment: in this line
`BaseClass baseClass = (BaseClass) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);`
 a have app crash